# How to user SafeERC20 from zeppelin-solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, user-safety

I am trying to utilize the  SafeERC20 library from zeppelin-solidity. 
However the instructions for using the library are not sufficient for a novice like me . 
Please help me in understanding . 
   /**
   * @title SafeERC20
   * @dev Wrappers around ERC20 operations that throw on failure.
 + * To use this library you can add a `using SafeERC20 for ERC20;` statement to your contract,
 + * which allows you to call the safe operations as `token.safeTransfer(...)`, etc.*/    when I utilize it in my Contract token program , How shall I use it ?
code is available here                  https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol
[image]

below is the code . 
https://gist.github.com/bhattnaval/2eea6398fab22e64140bef930243bacd

Comment: Hey Naval, what are you trying to do?  Do you have a token you're trying to transfer or are you looking to create a token?

Comment: I am trying to transfer the token from one owner to another . However I am not able to use the safeERC20's safetransfer . Sorry in the above code I had the statement wrong . it should be token.safeTransfer(Mytoken,msg.sender,_to,_value); but even that is giving an error . DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
              token.safeTransfer(Mytoken,msg.sender,_to,_value);
              ^---^

Comment: in case you would like to check the complete code . https://gist.github.com/bhattnaval/2eea6398fab22e64140bef930243bacd

Comment: yea I think you have quite a few issues going on here.  But for the safeTransfer, you can try safeERC20.safeTransfer();   Are you trying to create your own token or have a utility that handles multiple tokens?

Comment: Yes , I am trying to create my own token.  I checked the helper zeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/SafeERC20Helper.sol. However, I am not able to grasp the idea . specifically ,  function SafeERC20Helper() {
    failing = new ERC20FailingMock();
    succeeding = new ERC20SucceedingMock();
  }

Comment: if I try to do this the token address is different than my actual token contract address , but if I try using the actual function name it says you cant instantiate a function in itself . https://gist.github.com/bhattnaval/2fbf0ac57ce952d2f1e2a6e1f6118680

Answer (score 5):

The library SafeERC20 is to safely interact with a third party token. It is not to be used inside your own token contract.

OpenZeppelin contracts already have require to check for preconditions so they will return true or fail early.

Also I'd suggest to remove the protection for short address attack `onlyPayloadSize`. They were removed from the OpenZeppelin contracts several months ago [#261 Remove short address attack checks from tokens](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/261).